# From where to get JDK 7u131 patch

Tags: java, java-7

I need to upgrade my java version from 1.7.0_80-b15 to 131 patch. Problem is I am not able to get this update patch anywhere. Can anyone tell me from where to get this patch? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're going to update anyway, why not to a more recent/secure version?

Comment: some project depedency we have, so cant upgrade to recent one. This is needed to upgrade since this update have TLS1.1 and 1.2 support by default.

Comment: Oracle stopped supporting Java SE 7 after update 80. If you need this update, you need to pay Oracle for extended support. You cannot get it for free.